# How to convert letters into numbers and print out BTEC final grade

Tags: c#

I'm designing a BTEC grade calculator, for those that are not in the know; BTEC is a type of qualification done in the UK and has a 'different' point grading system mainly based on coursework. There is a number of units (20) and each unit you can get a pass, merit and distinction on each unit. Each pass, merit and distinction add up to so many points and these points add up to the overall grade.

For example, a score of 120 points would map to a PPP grade, 240 points would map to MMM and so on.

I've written a program based on the following Pseudo Code:

```
Prompt for student name:
Operator enters student name
Operator enters their grade units one at a time (D, M, P, D etc):
Display Message about final grade:
    Your final Grade is:
    DMM
```

Below is my current code but it needs to be changed and fixed.  At the moment, I need to enter unit grades as numbers (20, 40).  I want to be able to enter the grade letter (D,M,P).  How do I change my program so that it can interpret letters and map them to the unit score?

I am also having an issue converting from a final score to a final grade.  At the moment, if I enter two unit grades of 80, giving a total score of 160, the grade displayed should be MPP, however it is printing 120.  What am I doing wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter;
        double score;

        while (true)
        {
            counter = 1;
            score = 0.0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Name or type 'exit' to quit): ");
            // Naming for exiting 
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            if (name == "exit")
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                int numberOfUnits = 20;
                Console.WriteLine("Number of Units:  ");
                numberOfUnits = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                while (counter <= numberOfUnits)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Final Grade Score {0}", counter);
                    score += double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    counter++;
                }
                // Add up and print letter grade. 
                score = (score / (counter - 1));
                if (score < 120)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: PPP");
                }
                else if (score < 160)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: MPP");
                }
                else if (score < 200)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: MMP");
                }
                else if (score < 240)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: MMM");
                }
                else if (score < 280)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: DMM");
                }
                else if (score < 320)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: DDM");
                }
                else if (score < 360)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: DDD");
                }
                    // After DDD it goes up by 20's ..... D* = 20 not 40...
                else if (score < 380)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: D*DD");
                }
                else if (score < 400)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: D*D*D");
                }
                else if (score < 420)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: D*D*D*");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Grade: {0}", (score).ToString("P"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed in its current form. You need to try to narrow the scope to what your actual problem is.  It sounds a bit like it is how to convert a letter such as p to a number like 40 but that's a guess. If that is the problem then you could use something as simple as a switch statement. But you need to clarify the problem.

Comment: @forsvarir I thought I clarified and wrote the problem out clearly? What I need help with is converting letters to numbers and the output to be a letter grade.

Comment: So in essence something like: `switch(console.read line()){case "P": score += 20;break;`   etc?

Comment: As for your PPP should be MPP issue, it may be related to you dividing score by counter which is probably 20, before checking its value. If you haven't already you should step through the code and see how score is being updated

Comment: @forsvarir Yes essentially, I will have to go over the code again for the PPP issue. How would I apply that switch statement and more importantly; where would i apply it within the code. Would you mind giving me an example? I am still very new to C# Thanks for your contribution so far =)

Comment: I don't have access to a computer until Monday and it looks like you have an example below. In general you should look into breaking up your logic into meaningful methods and possibly separate classes. A method for converting the read string into a number, a method for converting a score into a letter grade etc.  This will make it easier for you to write, understand and test your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with some small edits, and the switch statement to convert letters into numbers.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter;
        double score;

        while (true)
        {
            counter = 1;
            score = 0.0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Name or type 'exit' to quit): ");
            // Naming for exiting 
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            if (name == "exit")
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                int numberOfUnits = 20;
                Console.WriteLine("Number of Units:  ");
                numberOfUnits = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                while (counter <= numberOfUnits)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Final Grade Score {0}", counter);
                    string s = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                    double d;
                    if (double.TryParse(s, out d)) //parsing as a number was successfull, and the result is in d.
                        score += d;
                    else //parsing failed.
                    {
                        switch (s)
                        {
                            case "D":
                                score += 20;
                                break;
                            case "M":
                                score += 50;
                                break;
                            case "P":
                                score += 70;
                                break;
                            default:
                                counter--; //parsing of a letter failed. reducing counter that will be later incremented, to offset the effect.
                                Console.WriteLine("Could not parse your grade. Enter a number or a letter");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                // Add up and print letter grade. 
                score = (score / (counter - 1));

                if (score < 120) Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: PPP");
                else if (score < 160) Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: MPP");
                else if (score < 200) Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: MMP");
                else if (score < 240) Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: MMM");
                else if (score < 280) Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: DMM");
                else if (score < 320) Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: DDM");
                else if (score < 360) Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: DDD");
                // After DDD it goes up by 20's ..... D* = 20 not 40...
                else if (score < 380) Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: D*DD");
                else if (score < 400) Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: D*D*D");
                else if (score < 420) Console.WriteLine("Letter Grade: D*D*D*");
                Console.WriteLine("Grade: {0}", (score).ToString("P"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has quite a few issues, too many really for a SO question.  As I said in my comments, if you need to convert from an arbitrary string to a number, you could use a series of if statements, or a switch or you could use some kind of mapping.  As far as your problem converting back from a score to a grade, my impression is still that the issues is this line:

```
score = (score / (counter - 1));
```

It doesn't make sense to divide the score by the number of units.  If you got 20 points for each unit, dividing by the number of units would give you a final score of 20... that seems very wrong.

Part of the problem that you have is that you've coded up the whole thing in one function.  You really need to look at breaking up your code into logical units.  The units will be smaller, easier to understand and easier to test.  I would strongly recommend not writing very much at all in your main method.  Spin up another, relevant class and leave the work to it.  Below are some suggestions of an alternate approach to breaking down your program.  It's far from polished, but compare the two and see which is easier to understand.

```
// Main class.  This doesn't do anything but spin up a new class
// and tell it to get all student grades.
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var calculator = new BTECGradeCalculator();
        calculator.GetAllStudentGrades();
    }
}
```

The new BTECGradeCalculator consists of several functions.  The first thing I did was type in an interpretation of your pseudo code above and a new function:

```
public void GetAllStudentGrades() {
    while (true) {
        string studentName = PromptStudentAndGetName();
        if (studentName.ToUpper() == "EXIT") {
            return;
        }
        List<string> studentGrades = GetStudentGrades();
        int score = CalculateScoreFromGrades(studentGrades);
        string finalGrade = CalculateGradeFromScore(score);

        PrintFinalStatement(studentName, finalGrade);
    }
}
```

You can see that the function itself is almost entirely made of function calls.  Each one with a reasonably descriptive name (very subjective) so that the method almost reads like it is pseudo code.

I then implemented each of these methods.  Each one has a specific task, that matches its name.  This gives you a much better chance of trying to identify errors.  You could also make the methods public / move some of them to other classes and unit test them individually using a testing framework like nunit.

```
private string PromptStudentAndGetName() {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Name or type 'exit' to quit): ");
    return Console.ReadLine();
}


private List<string> GetStudentGrades() {
    List<string> grades = new List<string>();
    Console.WriteLine("Number of Units:  ");

    int numberOfUnits = GetNumberOfUnits();

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= numberOfUnits; ) {
        Console.WriteLine("What was your grade for unit {0}", counter);
        var grade = Console.ReadLine();
        if (IsValidGrade(grade)) {
            grades.Add(grade);
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("That's not a valid grade!");
        }
    }

    return grades;
}

private int CalculateScoreFromGrades(List<string> studentGrades) {
    int score = 0;
    foreach (var grade in studentGrades) {
        score += GetScoreFromGrade(grade);
    }
    return score;
}

private string CalculateGradeFromScore(int score) {
    if (score < 120) return "PPP";
    if (score < 160) return "MPP";
    if (score < 200) return "MMP";
    if (score < 240) return "MMM";
    if (score < 280) return "DMM";
    if (score < 320) return "DDM";
    if (score < 360) return "DDD";
    if (score < 380) return "D*DD";
    if (score < 400) return "D*D*D";
    if (score < 420) return "D*D*D*";
    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Unexpected score {0}", score));
}

private void PrintFinalStatement(string studentName, string finalGrade) {
    // Add up and print letter grade. 
    Console.WriteLine("Student: {0}", studentName);
    Console.WriteLine("Grade: {0}", finalGrade);
}
```

Notice that some of the methods were again broken down, to call out to other smaller methods in order to keep the code size manageable.  These methods are below:

```
private int GetNumberOfUnits() {
    int numberOfUnits;

    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfUnits)) {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry... I didn't understand that.  I'm going to assume you have the expected 20 units.");
        numberOfUnits = 20;
    }
    return numberOfUnits;
}

bool IsValidGrade(string grade) {
    string [] validGrades = {"D","M","P"};
    return validGrades.Contains(grade.ToUpper());
}

private int GetScoreFromGrade(string grade) {
    switch (grade.ToUpper()) {
        case "P":
            return 20;
        case "M":
            return 40;
        case "D":
            return 80;
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Tried to get a score from an invalid grade {0}", grade));
}
```

Notice also, that some of the above methods throw exceptions when they get into unexpected situations that contain information about the error, such as the unexpected score / grade to help identify the cause of issues.  As I've said, this is far from an ideal program, but it does hopefully suggest a direction to take in order to help you diagnose your own issues.